# Somehow I got this to execute without crashing, how do I print it?

Tags: c

I have a simple program that I have written way too many lines of code for. Its my second program. I have been looking at how to print this for two hours. How can I print a queue with multiple data types? Right before the free(customerArray); I need to add a print statement.

Sample Input

```
2

5

10 1 STEVEN 12

12 6 AHMAD 8

13 1 JENNY 40

22 6 JERMAINE 39

100000 12 AMALIA 53

6

100 1 A 100

200 2 B 99

300 3 C 98

400 4 D 97

500 5 E 96

600 6 F 95
```

Sample Output

```
STEVEN from line 1 checks out at time 100.

AHMAD from line 6 checks out at time 170.

JERMAINE from line 6 checks out at time 395.

JENNY from line 1 checks out at time 625.

AMALIA from line 12 checks out at time 100295.

A from line 1 checks out at time 630.

F from line 6 checks out at time 1135.

E from line 5 checks out at time 1645.

D from line 4 checks out at time 2160.

C from line 3 checks out at time 2680.

B from line 2 checks out at time 3205.
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// customer record
typedef char customerName[9];

typedef struct customer {
    customerName name;                  // 1-9 upper case letters
    int lineNumber;                     // line number customer gets on
    int time;                           // arrival time at line
    int numberItems;                    // number of items customer has
} customer;

// [singly linked] queue element
typedef customer *qitem;

typedef struct node {
    qitem data;                         // pointer to actual data
    struct node *next;                  // forward pointer to next item
} node;

// queue definition (singly linked list)
// NOTE:
typedef struct queue {
    node *front;                        // pointer to first node in list ie front of line with cashier
} queue;

// qinit -- initialize/reset queue
void qinit(queue *q)
{
    q->front = NULL;
}

// qempty -- returns 1 if empty or 0 if false
int qempty(queue *q)
{
    return (q->front == NULL);
}

// enqueue -- append element to end of queue
void enqueue(queue *q, qitem data)
{
    node *newnode;
    node *prev;

    newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->data = data;

    // find the back of the queue with only a front pointer
    prev = NULL;
    for (node *cur = q->front;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        prev = cur;

    // append to tail of list
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = newnode;

    // add to end of empty list
    else
        q->front = newnode;

}

// dequeue -- dequeue from the front of the queue
qitem dequeue(queue *q)
{
    node *curnode;
    qitem data;

    do {
        curnode = q->front;

        if (curnode == NULL) {
            data = NULL;
            break;
        }

        // get node's data value (e.g. pointer to customer struct)
        data = curnode->data;

        // release the node's storage back to the heap
        free(curnode);
    } while (0);

    return data;
}

// qfront -- peek at front of queue
qitem qfront(queue *q)
{
    node *curnode;
    qitem data;

    curnode = q->front;
    if (curnode != NULL)
        data = curnode->data;
    else
        data = NULL;

    return data;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int testCases = 0;
    scanf("%d", &testCases);

    if(testCases > 0 && testCases <= 25){//shortcircuiting???

    while (testCases--){

        int numCustomers;
        scanf("%d", &numCustomers);

        if(numCustomers < 0 || numCustomers > 11){
            return 0;
        }

        queue* customerArray = (queue*) malloc(sizeof(queue) * 12);

        for ( int i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++){
            qinit(customerArray);// starting new queue

            customer* newCustomer = (customer*) malloc(sizeof(customer));

            scanf("%d", &(newCustomer->time));
            scanf("%d", &(newCustomer->lineNumber));
            scanf("%s", newCustomer->name);
            scanf("%d", &(newCustomer->numberItems));
            enqueue(&customerArray[newCustomer->lineNumber - 1], newCustomer);
        }


        int totalTime = INT_MAX;

        for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
        {
        customer* frontCustomer = qfront(&customerArray[i]);

            if(frontCustomer== NULL){
                return 0;
            }

         if(totalTime < frontCustomer->time)
            {
                totalTime = frontCustomer->time;
            }

         }

       while(numCustomers--) {

        int customerToCheckOutLine = 0; int minNumberOfItems = INT_MAX;

        for( int j=11 ; j>=0; j--){

            customer* frontCustomer = qfront(&customerArray[j]);

            if(frontCustomer->time <= totalTime)
            {
                if(frontCustomer->numberItems < minNumberOfItems)
                {
                    customerToCheckOutLine = frontCustomer->lineNumber;
                    minNumberOfItems = frontCustomer->numberItems;
                }

            }
            free(frontCustomer);
        }


        customer* customerToCheckOut = qfront(&customerArray[customerToCheckOutLine -1 ]);
        totalTime += 30;
        totalTime += (customerToCheckOut->numberItems) * 5;
        dequeue(&customerArray[customerToCheckOutLine - 1]);
       }

        free(customerArray);

    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I need to add a print statement". Then why don't you do that? You haven't told us why you can't do what you want. Just add a `printCustomers` function that takes the customer queue as input and uses a loop to iterate over it printing out the info for each customer.

Comment: I couldn't do it beause im so new I didn't think of just making another function. Just thought it would be a single line. thanks for the help.

Comment: void printQueue(queue *q){
    
    qitem data;
    
    node *tmp = q->front;
    
    while(tmp != NULL){
        
        printf("%s from line %d checks out at time %d\n", tmp->data->name, tmp->data->lineNumber, tmp->data->totalTime);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    ;
    free(tmp);
}